# Why does 'safely removing device' from Ubuntu 18.04 takes ages?

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I sometimes write a large amount of files to an external hard disk (might take an hour or so). When that copy process is over I am clicking on

> Safely remove drive

after wich a message appears

> Device should not be unplugged

But that message is there for a LONG time! What can I do? Wait for 30 minutes? Or a day? Or a week?

What is going on? Why does it take so long time to safely remove the device? The data has been written, so what is going on?  How to improve/fix this situation?

Comment: Yes maybe. So basically the information presented to the user is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, a bit perhaps. How do you copy the files? I think when copying with `rsync` instead of `cp` the command only returns when the files are _really_ written.

Comment: I use the graphical interface (which has no name; maybe nautilus?) and drag and drop the files (several folders with videos in it).

Comment: @PerlDuck I'm not sure about rsync - I use that for backup, and I still have to wait for the buffers to flush.